# JS функция не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется JS функция:

```
function removeServiceItem() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

При ее запуске ничего не происходит, в чем ошибка?
HTML:

```
<button>Элемент <span onclick="removeServiceItem()">Убрать</span></button>
```

Comment: `console.log(this);`

Answer (score 2):

```js
function removeServiceItem(element) {
    console.log(element);
    $(element).parent().remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Элемент <span onclick="removeServiceItem(this)">Убрать</span></button>
```